# How to get an ordered list full with in Android browser

Tags: mobile, html-lists

This is probably really simple but I've been on it for ages and can't figure it out....

If I have a simple ordered list, which when I view it in Fire Fox, everything looks fine; the list is displayed the full width of the browser.

If I look at the same page in my Android browser, the list only takes up about a third the width of the screen.

I don't understand it, I have no CSS rules applied so why should the Android browser not use the full width of the screen?

Here's my HTML:

```
<html>
<head>      
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>

<body>
<h2 style="text-align:center">This is a long heading which stretches across the page</h2>
<ol>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque dolor diam, lobortis eu volutpat in, accumsan vel massa. Curabitur justo mauris, tempus ut feugiat nec, pellentesque et felis. Proin aliquam varius mi a ultrices. Nam purus tellus, posuere hendrerit tristique at, blandit eu tellus. Curabitur egestas diam at nunc volutpat rhoncus. Cras elementum, magna id tristique porta, justo leo ultrices nisl, et rhoncus magna odio id purus. Aenean pretium augue ut metus congue sed lobortis urna varius. Duis augue diam, posuere sit amet viverra vel, facilisis ac odio. Vestibulum nisi orci, luctus vitae luctus eget, lacinia ut dui. Ut imperdiet, enim nec mattis laoreet, tellus elit bibendum elit, non imperdiet enim mauris eu risus. Curabitur faucibus urna sed turpis tincidunt pulvinar. Etiam tristique nisl eu nibh sodales at convallis mi mattis. Fusce imperdiet posuere lorem quis vulputate. Ut in leo in lorem fermentum hendrerit quis vitae velit. Phasellus tristique mi ac neque tempus sollicitudin. In nec interdum enim. Fusce id magna et ipsum lobortis cursus. Nunc eleifend volutpat elit, a adipiscing tellus posuere et. Phasellus id mauris ante, vehicula suscipit leo.</li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque dolor diam, lobortis eu volutpat in, accumsan vel massa. Curabitur justo mauris, tempus ut feugiat nec, pellentesque et felis. Proin aliquam varius mi a ultrices. Nam purus tellus, posuere hendrerit tristique at, blandit eu tellus. Curabitur egestas diam at nunc volutpat rhoncus. Cras elementum, magna id tristique porta, justo leo ultrices nisl, et rhoncus magna odio id purus. Aenean pretium augue ut metus congue sed lobortis urna varius. Duis augue diam, posuere sit amet viverra vel, facilisis ac odio. Vestibulum nisi orci, luctus vitae luctus eget, lacinia ut dui. Ut imperdiet, enim nec mattis laoreet, tellus elit bibendum elit, non imperdiet enim mauris eu risus. Curabitur faucibus urna sed turpis tincidunt pulvinar. Etiam tristique nisl eu nibh sodales at convallis mi mattis. Fusce imperdiet posuere lorem quis vulputate. Ut in leo in lorem fermentum hendrerit quis vitae velit. Phasellus tristique mi ac neque tempus sollicitudin. In nec interdum enim. Fusce id magna et ipsum lobortis cursus. Nunc eleifend volutpat elit, a adipiscing tellus posuere et. Phasellus id mauris ante, vehicula suscipit leo.</li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque dolor diam, lobortis eu volutpat in, accumsan vel massa. Curabitur justo mauris, tempus ut feugiat nec, pellentesque et felis. Proin aliquam varius mi a ultrices. Nam purus tellus, posuere hendrerit tristique at, blandit eu tellus. Curabitur egestas diam at nunc volutpat rhoncus. Cras elementum, magna id tristique porta, justo leo ultrices nisl, et rhoncus magna odio id purus. Aenean pretium augue ut metus congue sed lobortis urna varius. Duis augue diam, posuere sit amet viverra vel, facilisis ac odio. Vestibulum nisi orci, luctus vitae luctus eget, lacinia ut dui. Ut imperdiet, enim nec mattis laoreet, tellus elit bibendum elit, non imperdiet enim mauris eu risus. Curabitur faucibus urna sed turpis tincidunt pulvinar. Etiam tristique nisl eu nibh sodales at convallis mi mattis. Fusce imperdiet posuere lorem quis vulputate. Ut in leo in lorem fermentum hendrerit quis vitae velit. Phasellus tristique mi ac neque tempus sollicitudin. In nec interdum enim. Fusce id magna et ipsum lobortis cursus. Nunc eleifend volutpat elit, a adipiscing tellus posuere et. Phasellus id mauris ante, vehicula suscipit leo.</li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque dolor diam, lobortis eu volutpat in, accumsan vel massa. Curabitur justo mauris, tempus ut feugiat nec, pellentesque et felis. Proin aliquam varius mi a ultrices. Nam purus tellus, posuere hendrerit tristique at, blandit eu tellus. Curabitur egestas diam at nunc volutpat rhoncus. Cras elementum, magna id tristique porta, justo leo ultrices nisl, et rhoncus magna odio id purus. Aenean pretium augue ut metus congue sed lobortis urna varius. Duis augue diam, posuere sit amet viverra vel, facilisis ac odio. Vestibulum nisi orci, luctus vitae luctus eget, lacinia ut dui. Ut imperdiet, enim nec mattis laoreet, tellus elit bibendum elit, non imperdiet enim mauris eu risus. Curabitur faucibus urna sed turpis tincidunt pulvinar. Etiam tristique nisl eu nibh sodales at convallis mi mattis. Fusce imperdiet posuere lorem quis vulputate. Ut in leo in lorem fermentum hendrerit quis vitae velit. Phasellus tristique mi ac neque tempus sollicitudin. In nec interdum enim. Fusce id magna et ipsum lobortis cursus. Nunc eleifend volutpat elit, a adipiscing tellus posuere et. Phasellus id mauris ante, vehicula suscipit leo.</li>
</ol>

</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Screenshot follows

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody has this same problem, I've found the answer - it is a bug with Android autofit in ICS & JB. Gingerbread seems ok.

The answer is here - [android autofit mode causing issues with css width in web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508889/android-autofit-mode-causing-issues-with-css-width-in-web-page)

Just apply this workaround to the  in question

```
/* work around mobile device auto-fitting */
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 800px) {
   #content p {
       background-image:url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==); 
       background-repeat:repeat;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following meta tag between your head tags:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

It allows you to control the viewport's size and scale. If you need more info visit this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag).

Comment: Thanks Meda, but that doesn't give me the effect I'm after. With my original code, the heading between the <h2> tags does take up the full width of the screen, it's just the <ol> that doesn't. If I add the viewport meta, the heading is so big it wraps across 3 lines

Comment: but what about the <ol> text? does it fill the whole screen, because I tested on my device it works

Comment: it does, but it still wraps after 4 or 5 words

Comment: @Damian can you upload some screenshot? Im getting the same result on chrome, firefox and android browser

Comment: I've just uploaded a screenshot to my original question

Comment: I'm running Android 4.1.2 - Jelly Bean on my Galaxy S2, so if you're running an older version it may be a bug in the new browser?

Comment: ok So what is the issue after you add the meta tag, you want the h2 to fit in one line ? have you try using a smaller heading like h3 h4 or h5

Comment: I'd like all the text to remain the same height, I'd just like the text inside the <ol> to wrap when it reaches the right hand side of the screen, rather than wrapping after 5 or 6 words the way it is now. It should be able to fit around 20 words on each line before wrapping

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32108/discussion-between-meda-and-damian)