# How to over-ride mobile browser(s) auto-fit?

Tags: java, php, html, css

The text in certain standard tables and/or divs on a page is simply hanging left of the table and is wrapping at about 30% of the entire table.

I have narrowed down the issue to the "Auto Fit" feature many mobile browsers have and it appears to span across all mobile browser's i've tried. Once auto-fit is disabled, the page appears properly.

Is there any way to over-ride the auto-fit feature?

Comment: look up "meta viewport"

Answer (score 0):

here is a helpful article that you should read:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

You can use the viewport meta tag, as explained in the article above

Comment: The exact issue here. Resolved it with the blank.png http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508889/android-autofit-mode-causing-issues-with-css-width-in-web-page