# Target android browser only in CSS

Tags: css, android-browser

Is there a way to target the Android default browser in CSS? Something similar to either the `<!--[if IE 6]><![endif]-->` tags, or the `@-moz-document url-prefix() {}`?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to detect only Android browsers with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771372/is-there-any-way-to-detect-only-android-browsers-with-css)

Comment: Why would you want to target Android specifically?

Comment: Because the default browser's inconsistent adherence to standards is almost as bad as Internet Explorer!

Comment: Because the vastly different screen sizes and resolutions combined with lack of support for floats in Android Mail makes designing email that works on Android as well as everything else very, very difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Way. There are not Conditional comments or special CSS-Prefixes for Android!

You can check the UserAgent with JavaScript or jQuery and embed then a CSS only for Andoid.

Comment: Grrrr... too bad. Thanks :)

Comment: Please take care that JS conditional loading may be something late, so You may see the elements without style for moments.